# resolve site hostname inside docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dns, resolve

Can't resolve site nginx host inside docker nginx (and other in same network) container.

```sh
➜  dockerised-php git:(master) ✗ tree .
.
├── code
│   └── index.php
├── docker-compose.yml
├── README.md
└── site.conf

1 directory, 4 files
```

- site.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name docker-test.loc;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

- docker-compose

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
            - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        networks:
            - code-network
    php:
        image: php:fpm
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
        networks:
            - code-network

networks:
  code-network:
```

- `docker-test.loc` resolving from browser, but

```sh
docker exec -it dockerised-php_web_1 bash

nslookup docker-test.loc
# connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

- outside

```sh
➜  ~ nslookup docker-test.loc
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   docker-test.loc
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

- docker container resolver:

```
➜  ~ docker exec -it dockerised-php_web_1 bash
root@6340952094ed:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search Dlink
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

I tried `cat "127.0.0.1 docker-test.loc" >> /etc/hosts` inside nginx container but it not helps.

What should I do to resolve `docker-test.loc` inside container?

Comment: You say you can resolve that host name from the browser; what have you changed to make that possible?  (Did you edit the host's `/etc/hosts` file, configure dnsmasq or another DNS server, something else?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit *docker-compose.yml* file to add `container_name` for web service like that:

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        container_name: docker-test.loc
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
            - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        networks:
            - code-network
    php:
        image: php:fpm
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
        networks:
            - code-network

networks:
  code-network:
```

Then all container in the `code-network` can resolve `docker-test.loc` as IP address of your `web`-service container in your docker compose.

**EDIT**
For more than one hostname(virtualhost) in your nginx container you can use `external_links` like that:

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
            - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        networks:
            - code-network
    php:
        image: php:fpm
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
        networks:
            - code-network
        external_links:
            - web:docker-test__1.loc
            - web:docker-test__2.loc
            - web:abcdef.vn

networks:
  code-network:
```

Thanks.

Comment: ok, it's works. But if I have multiple vhosts in nginx container? How I should curl it?

Comment: I want isolated network (not `network_mode: host`) and do smth like `curl docker-test__1.loc && curl docker-test__2.loc`